# How do I select correctly an image out of my database?

Tags: php

```
<?php   $query="SELECT * from about";
                        $result=mysql_query($query);
                        $num=mysql_numrows($result);



                        $i=0;
                        while ($i < $num) {

                            $image=mysql_result($result,$i,"image");


                            echo "<img src='.$image.' alt=\"About\" />";

                        $i++;
                        }

        ?>
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here, can someone help me please? Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Comment: echo "<img src=\"$image\" alt=\"About\" />"; THis is what I have now

Comment: Is the "image" field a URL? What does the HTML show?

Comment: Does the `image` field actually contain a URL to the image? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Output of image field would be helpful.

Comment: And HTML show nothing but an empty frame

Comment: AED1302878157_159_clients_image_ient01.png
Thats's how the images are stored in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<img src=".$row['image']." alt=\"About\" />";
  }
}
```

edit: wrong string operators

Comment: please provide the fieldtypes of your db.

Comment: it's a varchar(254) and id is a bgint(11)

Comment: what exactly is contained? a path? relative? absolute?

Comment: Hopefully this is a correct answer 'cause I'm a newby
AED1302877695_998_about_image__about.png
This is what the database contains

Comment: so you may have only the file name stored, but not the relative path. try to add echo "<img src=\"path/to/images/".$row['image']."\" alt=\"About\" />";